# how to make auto reply App in xamarin for whatsapp

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how to make auto reply App in xamarin for whatsapp
like these app on store
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pransuinc.autoreply
or
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tkstudio.autoresponderforwa

it use notification for reply, is there possible in xamarin?

Comment: Hello Amer, the stack overflow community isn't designed to answer yes/no questions or provide you with full working solutions. We are best used to help you understand, adapt, or improve upon existing attempts at developing your required scenario.

Comment: I did not want full working
i need way to access of notification

Answer (score 1):

If your question is, "Is it possible?", the answer is Yes.

Since it can be done in Java/Kotlin, it can be done in C# using Xamarin. You will be using the exact same apis and that's the beauty of Xamarin.

Comment: How access to notification for send replay?

Comment: "Android Notification Channels" is your topic of research https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106314/android-oreo-notification-channels

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56659371/notification-extra-getstring-returns-empty-while-it-contains-data?noredirect=1#comment99911952_56659371 This one's an example of a guy getting notifications from Spotify & Google Play Music