# Notification.Extra.GetString returns empty while it contains data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a NotificationListener for my app that is supposed to listen to media player notifications like Spotify or GPM. This is the code for the OnListenerConnected override:

```cs
public override void OnListenerConnected()
        {
            base.OnListenerConnected();

            Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "OnListenerConnected (NLService): Listener connected");

            foreach (StatusBarNotification sbn in GetActiveNotifications())
            {
                if (sbn.Notification.Category == "transport")
                {
                    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Info, "SmartLyrics", "EXTRAS " + sbn.Notification.Extras.ToString());

                    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Verbose, "SmartLyrics", "Song Title - " + sbn.Notification.Extras.GetString("android.title"));
                    Log.WriteLine(LogPriority.Verbose, "SmartLyrics", "Song Artist - " + sbn.Notification.Extras.GetString("android.text"));
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that this is what I recieve in the LogCat:

```
06-18 23:36:05.405: I/SmartLyrics(25456): EXTRAS Bundle[{android.title=Kimigaite Mizuninaru, android.reduced.images=true, 
android.subText=Tadashii Itsuwarikarano Kishou, android.template=android.app.Notification$MediaStyle, 
android.showChronometer=false, android.icon=2130838406, 
android.text=ZUTOMAYO, android.progress=0, 
android.progressMax=0, android.appInfo=ApplicationInfo{34055c8 com.google.android.music} //... it goes on for a bit more}]
06-18 23:36:05.405: V/SmartLyrics(25456): Song Title - Kimigaite Mizuninaru
06-18 23:36:05.406: V/SmartLyrics(25456): Song Artist - ZUTOMAYO

06-18 23:36:05.516: I/SmartLyrics(25456): EXTRAS Bundle[{android.title=Veridis Quo, android.reduced.images=true, 
android.subText=Songs, android.template=android.app.Notification$MediaStyle, 
android.showChronometer=false, android.icon=2131231377, 
android.text=Daft Punk, android.progress=0, 
android.progressMax=0, android.appInfo=ApplicationInfo{8ca15e0 com.spotify.music} //... it goes on for a bit more}]
06-18 23:36:05.517: V/SmartLyrics(25456): Song Title - 
06-18 23:36:05.517: V/SmartLyrics(25456): Song Artist -
```

*(edited slightly for readability)*
You can see that it gets the notifications for both Google Play Music and Spotify, but even though the `Extras.ToString()` shows that `android.title` and `android.text` have values, the ``GetString` method doesn't show anything on the log.

I really have no idea what I going on. I thought about maybe using a RegEx to cut down the `Extras.ToString()` only to what I need but that doesn't look like a good solution. Any help here?

**EDIT:** To clarify that this is consistent, I've tested multiple times with YouTube Vanced, GPM and Spotify and only GPM prints the information on the log.

Comment: You can check if `sbn.Notification.Extras.ToString() != null`. But as you have it currently, it should atleast print `V/SmartLyrics(25456): EXTRAS null`

Comment: Do you have the right meta data filters on? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/guides/android-media-notifications/ Apart from that it looks right. I would just extract the data from sbn.Notification.Extras.ToString() and parse it so you can use it

Comment: @Saamer I'm pretty sure that what you have linked is something pretty different from what I want and have already set up here, this is specifically for Spotify and my code should work for any media notification. I think I'll just parse the Extras.ToString, I really have absolutely no idea how to fix this.